# Why is there a different result for IType.getAnnotation("Annotation") and IType.getAnnotations()?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-jdt

I have developed a custom Eclipse Builder, which reads metadata from type annotations.

Whenever I remove the desired annotation from a type, the following code still gets the IAnnotation object in the next build run (of course it should get it in the first run before the annotation is deleted):

```
IType type
IAnnotation myAnnotation = type.getAnnotation("MyAnnotation");
```

But if I use the following code, the annotation is not found:

```
IType type
IAnnotation[] myAnnotation = type.getAnnotations();
```

Why can I get in the first example the annotation but not in the second one?

Comment: Hmm, sounds similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011348/weird-javacore-itype-cache-problem